# Product Category

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and consider the product category $\mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \times \mathcal{C}$. I am confused about how arrows look like here. Suppose we have arrows $f,g$ in $\mathcal{C}$ with $f: A \to A'$ and $g: B \to B'$. Then $f: A' \to A \in \mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}(A',A)$.

We then have $(f,g) \in \mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}(A',A) \times \mathcal{C}(B,B')$ if I'm not mistaken.

But what is the domain and codomain of $(f,g)$? That's where I get consfused.

Comment: Domain $(A',B)$ and codomain $(A,B')$ surely?

Comment: You really should write the morphism $A' \to A$ in $C^{op}$ as something like $f^{op}$ to avoid confusion. It is not the same morphism as $f$ and shouldn't have the same name. (For bonus points also write $(A')^{op}$ and $A^{op}$, although at this point it's getting unwieldy.)

Comment: Yeah that is what confuses me too, I though they were the same, because the definition in my syllabus is $\mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}(A,B) := \mathcal{C}(B,A)$. So that means they are literally the same objects?

Comment: It may be *literally* the same object, but spiritually it's in a different category and has a different domain and codomain. That said, most authors don't use any special notation for the corresponding morphism in the opposite category.

Comment: The definition $\mathcal C^{\rm op} (A,B) := \mathcal C (B,A)$ is slick and quick, but it is confusing because we do not _syntactically_ differentiate between the morphisms of $\mathrm C^{\rm op}$ and the one of $\mathcal C$. A better formal definition would be $\mathcal C^{\rm op}(A,B) := \{f^{\rm op} \in \mathcal A_{A,B}^\ast : f \in \mathcal C(A,B)\}$ where $\mathcal A_{A,B}$ is the alphabet with letters the elements of $\mathcal C(A,B) \sqcup \{{}^{\rm op}\}$. As you see it is very cumbersome so one has to read between the lines.